# Pass multiple params handlebars each block

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

So I'm trying to render two form information within a view I can get the one forms information to render however I can't get the second form to render the necessary information.

Here is what I have so far.

```
<tbody>
                {{#each poemRegistrations}}
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="/dashboard/users/{{_id}}/progress">{{schoolName}}</a></td>
                    <td>{{competitionResults.winnersName}}</td>
                    <td>{{poem1AuthorName}}</td>
                    <td>{{poem1Title}}</td>
                    <td>{{poem1Url}}</td>
          <td>{{poem2AuthorName}}</td>
                    <td>{{poem2Title}}</td>
                    <td>{{poem2Url}}</td>
          <td>{{poem3AuthorName}}</td>
                    <td>{{poem3Title}}</td>
                    <td>{{poem3Url}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="btn-group">
              <a href="/dashboard/users/forms/poem-registrations/{{_id}}">
                                <button class="btn">Show</button>
                            </a>
              <a href="/dashboard/users/forms/poem-registrations/edit/{{_id}}">
                                <button class="btn">Edit</button>
                            </a>
              <a href="/dashboard/users/forms/poem-registrations/delete/{{_id}}">
                                <button class="btn user-btn-danger">Delete</button>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                {{/each}}

router.get('/dashboard/all-poems', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
  PoemRegistrations.find({}, function(err, poemRegistrations, competitionResults) {
    res.render('dashboard/all-poems.hbs', {
      pageTitle: 'All Poems',
      poemRegistrations: poemRegistrations,
      competitionResults: competitionResults
    });
  });
});
```

The PoemRegistration form information is rendering however I just want to get the winners name from another form.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Could you please share the JSON data?

Comment: Could you please elaborate what you mean with "get winners name from another form" is that another collection? or how you wanna fetch them. A minimal example would also be nice.

Comment: @CristianS. I have two forms, poem registration and competition results, I need to be able to render the information from the poem registration form (which I can do) but also I need to be able get the winnersName from the competition form.

Comment: @GibinEalias https://gist.github.com/benbagley/1e32b4ed0634ce22d7000bfcda6a1e65

Comment: You might consider appending both the results onto one JSON.

Comment: How would I do this @GibinEalias?

Answer (score 2):

You may use the `{{@root}}` helper in Handlebars V2.0.0 :`{{@root.competitionResults.winnersName}}`

Or you could also include `../` segments to change the context to the root : `{{../competitionResults.winnersName}}`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Could you please share the JSON data?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/benbagley/1e32b4ed0634ce22d7000bfcda6a1e65 this is using `<td>{{@root.competitionResults.winnersName}}</td>` it's only showing poemregistrations and not the winnersName from the results form.

Comment: So basically your input data (JSON) is incorrect or incomplete. Which is not a Handlebars issue.